# Use Audacity or other program to deepen voice for skype

Tags: audacity, voice-manipulation

I want to be able to deepen my voice for skype/video games, live, but am not sure how to do this. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why would you want to deepen your voice?

Comment: I'll get back to you tomorrow, I wrote a little tutorial before on how to add FX to your voice over skype but I'm away right now

Comment: No matter what you do the voice will sound 'off' and they will be able to tell.

Answer (score 2):

1. Get an audio host such as FL Studio or Cockos Reaper
2. Download an audio repeater called Virtual Audio Cable (VAC) and make sure you run the program as administrator
3. In the control panel, configure soundcard playback to primary speakers driver and configure soundcard recording to primary mic driver
4. Open the audio host and put the Pitch effect on the master mixer track
5. In the audio program, configure the audio settings to an ASIO driver and set audio input to the primary mic driver and audio output to VAC Cable 1
6. Use the audio repeater to set wave in to VAC Cable 1 and wave out to VAC Cable 2
7. Connect the skype audio output to VAC Cable 2

Comment: Can I have a bit more detailed explanation? IE: Speakers driver for what? The one that came with my computer? Or the audio host? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

How deep are we talking here?

In a pinch, and with certain types of mics, you just talk REALLY CLOSE to the microphone and have it reproduce a prominent bass effect.